# SQL table LEFT OUTER join query

Tags: sql, join

[image]

What's the solution for attached image? How to remove null?

`ClosingQty` column should reflect the value purchase-sale, but its reflecting null value

Comment: Please remove the C# tag and add tags for your specific database.

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your solution is failing as S.QUANTITY is NULL, so any arithmetic on it will result in a NULL answer. You will need to check for null, and replace with a valid number, for example 0.

The following should work:

`ISNULL(P.QUANTITY,0) - ISNULL(S.QUANTITY, 0) AS ClosingQty`

The real question, though, is why is S.QUANTITY null in the first place?

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that `NULL` is not the same as 0. Try this:

```
P.Quantity-COALESCE(S.Quantity,0) AS ClosingQty
```

See here: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_isnull.asp